# how to change the css property of absolute position div with parent div id

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="disp"> 
   <div>
      hi how are u
   </div>
   <div style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:100px;">
      hello
   </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#disp").css({"background-color":"#00ff00"});
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here it's giving blue color for "hi how are u" but it's not reflect in next div because it's in position:absolute how to make it part of parent div

Answer (score 1):

`.val` is used for the value property of `<input>`s, the value of the selectedIndex option of `<select>`s, et. al.

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but I think you mean to use `.html` instead.

Comment: i didn't mean about .val   <div id="show">
  <div style="position:absolute">
     <div  style="position:absolute">
            <h1>hi</h1>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
here i one parent div which contain two aboslute position div .if i want to access child with parent id how can do

Answer (score 1):

use `.text()` instead:

```
alert($("#show").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it looks to me like you need to do this:

```
$("#show").children();
```

This will return all the children DOM objects underneath the div with the ID "show". You can test it out by doing this command:

```
console.log($("#show").children());
```

This will post your objects to the console. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can try this also
alert($("#show").html());